# Is jQuery $.cache deprecated from 2.x?

Tags: jquery

When I try to print value of $.cache to console I get undefined.  I searched and could find no record of if this was deprecated?

I found this code:

```js
$("button").click( function() {
    $("#target")[0].innerHTML = "";
    $("<div>").appendTo( $("#target")).click( $.noop );
    $("#log").text( Object.keys( $.cache ).length );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>leak</button>
<div id="target"></div>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

If you raise jquery above 1.12 it no longer works so I am suspecting it is deprecated.

Is there something similar where I can print value of all cached jquery objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older jQuery versions, there is an object `jQuery.cache`.  It is used for internal purposes where jQuery stores data that is related to particular DOM nodes like where:

```
$(selector).data("foo", "whatever");
```

data would be stored.  It has no public documentation and is not intended to be used directly.

In fact, in the jQuery source, you can see that `$.data()` calls `internalData()` which uses `jQuery.cache`.

In newer jQuery versions (2.x and higher), jQuery uses two internal data objects called `data_user` and `data_priv` to store this type of state in and those objects are private and are not available via `jQuery.cache`.

It appears (though I haven't tracked actual source control version history to verify) that this architecture changed starting with version 2.x.

> Is jQuery $.cache deprecated from 2.x?

Yes, it appears to be removed from 2.x and higher and replaced with a private internal data structure.

> Is there something similar where I can print value of all cached
>   jquery objects?

Not that I'm aware of.  Keep in mind, it wasn't really a cache of DOM objects or jQuery objects, but rather a private store of data related to DOM objects.

---

If you can describe what problem you're really trying to solve, we could probably help you better find a way to approach that.

---

FYI, the jQuery 2.1 source has this comment which somewhat describes the motivation for changing the architecture:

```
/*
    Implementation Summary

    1. Enforce API surface and semantic compatibility with 1.9.x branch
    2. Improve the module's maintainability by reducing the storage
        paths to a single mechanism.
    3. Use the same single mechanism to support "private" and "user" data.
    4. _Never_ expose "private" data to user code (TODO: Drop _data, _removeData)
    5. Avoid exposing implementation details on user objects (eg. expando properties)
    6. Provide a clear path for implementation upgrade to WeakMap in 2014
*/
```

The last one probably explains why they want to hide the implementation details here because eventually they want to change the implementation to use a `WeakMap` which will work differently internally so they don't want anyone coding to their current internal data structure.

Comment: Thanks jfriend, similar to the fiddle link, I was wanting to watch the cache to see if it is building up exponentially and if entries that shouldn't be staying are staying or growing.

Comment: @jensanity5000 - Added some more to the end of my answer.  I don't think there is any way to get at the new internal data structure without making an edited version of jQuery for your own testing purposes.